# Tomcat/TomEE loses changes to catalina.sh and server.xml

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat, apache-tomee

I am trying to setup [Jaas and TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-jaas.html). So I created a TomEE installation using [Generating a TomEE-Project with Maven](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-mp-getting-started.html) and I am doing the required changes to catalina.sh and server.xml, but everytime I run TomEE, the changes I made into catalina.sh server.xml are lost. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost changes because, to start TomEE, I used the command

```
mvn package tomee:run
```

that overwrites the settings with the defaults

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer you can persist changes putting the config (tomee.xml, system.properties, ...) in src/main/tomee/conf.

Side note: another advantage is using:

```
mvn tomee:build
```

you can create a zip with tomee and your config.